# How do you say ‘he turns out to be...’ in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

How do I say ‘He turns out to be a good guy’ in Castilian Spanish?

> *Resulté un buen hombre*

Comment: If you are talking about “him” then it is _«Resultó (ser) un buen tipo»_.  The construcion is correct and it is used, you just missed the conjugation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Resultó ser un buen hombre'
*He* is implicit; It is part of the past tense for the verb *resultar*
Also, we need the *ser* (to be)
Optionally, instead of *hombre*, we may say *persona* (person), since *hombre* is commonly used to mean "an adult man", but if the guy is let's say 20 years old or less,then *hombre* is misleading.
so, 'Resultó ser una buena persona' works well for a man of any age. (Except for young kids)
Notice that *persona* does not have gender, it can be used for men as well as women.

Comment: Improvement: The answer is in present, not in the past. So, for 'He turns out to be...': 'Resulta que es...'. But 'He turned out to be...': 'Resultó ser...'